# Check object size in AngularJS template, doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I want to iterate through `myObject` in an AngularJS template

**This does not work :**

```
<ul ng-if="Object.keys(myObject).length">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in myObject">
        Value at key {{ key }} is: {{ val }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Nothing shows up, I suspect because `$scope.Object` is not defined.

**Instead, I did this :**

In the controller/directive :

```
$scope.sizeOf = function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
};
```

In the template :

```
<ul ng-if="sizeOf(myObject)">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in myObject">
        Value at key {{ key }} is: {{ val }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I do not like this solution because of the duplication of this function in every single controller or directive `$scope`.

**Do you see any cleaner solution?**

Thanks !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `Object` in `ngIf` directive everywhere. Just put its reference to the root scope:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.Object = Object;
});
```

It will also be available in isolated scopes such as in directives.

**UPD**. In recent version of Angular you can't reference `Object` in expressions anymore. In this case you will need to reference methods individually:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.keys = Object.keys;
});
```

and then use this function:

```
ng-if="keys(myObject).length"
```

Comment: I used your answer : mentions `app.run` and `$rootScope`, which are the best place where to put this, thanks

Comment: Now (1.2.23 and 1.3.0) they not allow access `$rootScope's childs` from template anymore. see https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecobj?p0=%7Bdisabled:cartScroll.first>%3D(Object.keys(cart_data.products).length-2)%7D

Comment: Found Useful! Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 11):

In your controller, add this line

```
$scope.Object = Object;
```

Then you should be able to use Object.XXX in your template like what you did.

Comment: Or even: `$rootScope.Object = Object;`. It can be set in the topmost controller and be available everywhere in templates.

Comment: Will this make `Object` available to isolated scopes as well ? If not, how to extend the prototype of default isolated scope ?

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives me error `Referencing Object in Angular expressions is disallowed! Expression`

Answer (score 7):

Shouldn't this be sufficient?

```
<ul ng-if="myObject">
  <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in myObject">
      Value at key {{ key }} is: {{ val }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The directive takes care of null, undefined, empty objects. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bE5ndaOiAbr3iN2gxULG?p=preview) for demo. Try modifying object to undefined, null or populate with value.

Comment: It will leave `<ul></ul>`.

Comment: Yep, I need to get rid of `<ul>` should the object by empty.

Comment: Yes I see that is the **only** edge case otherwise the simplest would be as shown above in my update.